# C# datable.select with convert fails - why?

Tags: c#, datatable.select

My code is comparing a passed in integer parameter to a datatable with corresponding string column. The real problem is that often the string value is preceded with 1 or more zeros. so I end up comparing string "000123" to integer 123 and they do not match.

So I would like to convert the string to an integer and compare as integers. I tried this but it doesn't work (I get error "Cannot find column [int]"):

```
var activeMedDup = ActiveMedications?.Select($"convert(int,strDDI) = '{dup.DDI}'")
```

Comment: You need to give a lot more context here. What is the structure of the table ActiveMedications? What are those dup.DDI and strDDI ?

Comment: What's your original query to get the datatable, or at least the structure of the datatable? Also [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: table has the column strDDI defined as a string and the param I am using to match it is an INTEGER- that's the problem

Comment: this works, but its embarrassing:

 string strDDI = DDI.ToString();

 var activeMedDup = ActiveMedications.Select($"DDI = '{strDDI}'").FirstOrDefault();

  if (activeMedDup == null)
            {
                strDDI = "0" + DDI.ToString();
                activeMedDup = ActiveMedications.Select($"DDI = '{strDDI}'").FirstOrDefault();
            }

Comment: I found a similar problem resolved here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2009/05/11/how-use-convert-in-a-datatable-select/

but a co-worker helped me re-write differently  using LINQ

Answer (score 0):

```
  var activeMedDup = ActiveMedications.Rows
                                        .OfType<DataRow>()
                                        .FirstOrDefault(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Field<string>("DDI")) == ddi);
```